# AdSense ads don't always appear on mobile and IE, is something wrong with Joomla?

Tags: google-adsense, joomla3

I am using Joomla 3.3 and placed AdSense ads on it. And I am facing a strange issue. Ads are displaying perfectly on Firefox and Chrome (updated) browsers, but not perfectly on mobile and Internet Explorer. The actual problem is that if I visit my site in IE, ads will not show but rest of the URLs are displaying ads . And if I do visit my site in mobile sometimes ads appear and some time don't. I just don't understand the actual problem, Although I have a 2 year old AdSense account.

I have searched a lot on other forums and many users are reporting same issue.

The second strange thing is if I open my domain with `index.php` then ads are serving fine. I think something is wrong with Joomla.

Comment: This question seems to be about Joomla specific issues, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3):

> And if i do visit my site in mobile some times ads appear and some
>   time dont.

Just to clarify something.

Adsense will attempt to display adverts **IF** there are adverts available. In some cases, there won't be an advert available, in which case a blank spot will be shown. Remember that Adsense will attempt to display adverts that are relevant to the user or the content that they are viewing. In my personal experience, these blank spots will become more prevalent if:

1. The content contains certain keywords that advertisers wish to avoid.
2. The content is thin (making it difficult for Adsense to display contextual adverts).
3. The user is browsing the site with a browser that has little-to-no search history (this will negatively affect Interest-based advertising). If you don't use Internet Explorer too much, this might be the cause of your worries. Try searching for a number of different topics using IE. Visit a few of the websites shown in the search results. Then retry.
4. The user has opted out of Interest-based advertising.

Have a read on [how Adsense chooses advertisements](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9713?hl=en).